# MLE derivation for RV that follows Binomial distribution

Tags: statistics

Looking at [Cambridge stats notes](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/stats/Sa4.pdf) (page 10). They have that $X \sim B(n,p)$ and they show that the log likelihood of the data is maximized when $\frac{x}{\hat{p}}-\frac{n-x}{1-\hat{p}} = 0$. But when I derive this, I have a plus in there:

$$\text{log likelihood}(p) = \log f(x|p) = \text{constant} + x \log{p} + (n-x) \log{1-p}$$

When you take a derivative of that with respect to $p$, you get:

$$\frac{x}{p} + \frac{n-x}{1-p}$$

What's wrong here?

Comment: ok I see... (1-p) in the third term..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we differentiate, we use chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dp}(x\log p + (n-x) \log (1-p))= \frac{x}{p}+\frac{n-x}{1-p}\frac{d}{dp}(1-p)=\frac{x}{p}-\frac{n-x}{1-p}$$